# Looking for Text Editor with File Browser for logs

Tags: software-recommendation, text-editor

Need a text editor with file browser that will keep files sorted by date and allow quickly switching between files in the editor. Lots of log files to view through quickly.

TextWrangler only shows files in disk browser by name. Lots of other editors don't even have a file browser. Loved Notepad++ on windows. Anything close on Mac?

Need:

- allow browsing file system
- sort files/folders by date modified
- quickly show/edit files in main window by clicking/double-clicking filenames (no popup of separate windows)

I've looked at log file viewers and they're mainly for viewing individual files. I have log files with semi-random names but I need them sorted by modified date to troubleshoot.

Comment: See [this post](http://meta.apple.stackexchange.com/a/2181/88313) for important guidelines that should be followed when asking for a software recommendation. It will help everyone by preventing unnecessary answers for items that don't fit your request.  - From Review

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Atom: https://atom.io

> **File system browser**
>
> Easily browse and open a single file, a whole project, or multiple
>   projects in one window.

With log files it looks like this:
[image: Atom]

Comment: how do I get the files sorted by date? I only see them sorted alpha

Comment: found a package that does exactly this: https://atom.io/packages/tree-view-sort

Comment: and even better, a pkg to color code log files: https://atom.io/packages/language-log